# Simple "proof" of Lebesgue outer measure of a closed interval, i.e., why am I wrong?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

Suppose that we already know $A \subseteq B \implies \lambda^*(A) \le \lambda^*(B)$ for $A, B \in \mathbb{R}$.

Then, consider a closed interval $[a, b]$ with $a < b$.  Then there exists some $\epsilon > 0$ such that $(a + \epsilon, b - \epsilon) \subseteq [a, b] \subseteq (a - \epsilon, b + \epsilon)$ and then $b - a - 2\epsilon = \lambda^*(a + \epsilon, b - \epsilon) \le \lambda^*([a, b]) \le \lambda^*(a - \epsilon, b + \epsilon) = b - a + 2\epsilon$ and so taking the supremum on the left and infimum on the right we should get $\lambda([a, b]) = b - a$.

I don't see why this wouldn't be valid, but the book I'm looking at warns the reader against a simple proof of this fact and then launches into a construction directly from the definition of $\lambda^*$ via the Heine-Borel theorem.

Is my proof correct or am I just blind to something obvious?

Comment: This uses $\lambda((a,b))=b-a$, so the author might want to avoid that?

Comment: How do you know the outer measure of an open interval is the difference of the endpoints? It is true, but I don't think it is immediately obvious from the definition.

Comment: I think this is right -- I had in mind was that the point was that $\lambda^*(a, b) = \lambda^*([a, b])$, but the measure of $(a, b)$ has yet to be considered.

Comment: Can you post how the outer measure is defined in your book?

Comment: Mind you that proving that $\lambda^*(a,b)=b-a$ must be at least as hard as proving that $(a,b)$ is uncountable.  After all countable sets have measure zero!

Comment: Btw, a key reason to start by proving the result for $[a,b]$ instead of $(a,b)$ is that $[a,b]$ is compact, so you can reduce an open cover to a finite subcover. Once you have the result for $[a,b]$, the result for $(a,b)$ follows easily by the containment $[a+\epsilon, b-\epsilon] \subset (a,b) \subset [a,b]$, similar to your argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof provided is valid if it is already known that $\lambda^*(a, b) = b - a$.  However, my confusion simply stemmed from assuming that given the definition of the length of an interval as $\ell(a, b) = b - a$ that it was also immediate for $\lambda^*$, which is not the case.  For completeness:

$$\lambda^*(A) = \text{inf}\{\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \ell(I_k)\ |\ I_1, ... \text{are open intervals s.t.}\ A \subseteq\bigcup_{k = 1}^\infty I_k\},$$

and where $A$ is any subset of $\mathbb{R}$.